# shell script to check if images in a folder are being used by a set of HTML files

Tags: linux, shell, filenames

Sometime ago I worked in a team that developed a bunch of educational softwares and now they are been reviewed for bugs and updates.
During this process, I noticed that the folder "imgs" accumulated too many files. Probably one of the developers decided to include all the images used by each of the softwares into the folder. However, because there are too many softwares, it would be too painful to check manually all of them (and some of the images are part of the layout, almost invisible).

Is there a way to write a shell script in Linux to check if the files in a given folder are being used by a set of HTML and JS files in another folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the images folder and try this

```
for name in *; { grep -ril $name /path/to/soft/* || echo "$name not used"; }
```

Comment: That is it!
Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure I understood your question correctly,
But maybe this will help you

```
ls -1 your_source_path | while read file
do
    grep -wnr "$file*" your_destination_path ||  
            echo "no matching for file $file"
            # you can set any extra action here 

done
```

in source_path you put director from hi will list all files name and destination where he should searching.

Comment: This is the kind of thing I am looking for. Thanks!

Two other things I need are:
1) make grep check folders recursively;
2) make easier to identify when grep does not find any match.
Is that possible?

Comment: yes, he already check folders recursively on destination side. If he find something, you should see in output full path to file and line number.

Comment: would be simple to create some alert in case it does not find any match?

Comment: Sure, You can always use or ( || ) for example. I modify my example and I hope You will finish the rest by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check for the generic case - since HTML and Javascript are two dynamic (e.g. the Javascript code could create the image file name on the file). Likewise, images can be specified in CSS style sheet, inline style, etc.

You want to review the HTML/JS files, and see if possible to identify the tags that are actually used to specify images. This will hopefully, reduce the number of XML tags and attribute names that need to be extracted.

As an alternative, if you have access to the 'access log' of the server, you can find out which images have been accessed over time, and focus the search on images not referenced in the log file.